# Problem understanding the Python interpreter internals

Tags: python, interpreter

I have this very short piece of code but it's hard for me to understand how the Python interpreter works. I create a list and a dictionary with that list.

```
lista = [1,2,3]
dict = {1: lista}
print(lista)
print(dict)
```

This is the output, nothing strange here:

```
[1, 2, 3]
{1: [1, 2, 3]}
```

However, if I change the list so it now contains the dictionary...

```
lista = [1, dict]
print(lista)
print(dict)
```

I got this output:

```
[1, {1: [1, 2, 3]}]
{1: [1, 2, 3]}
```

The list is updated and I would expect that the dictionary would have a copy of the updated list, but this is not happening. I realize that I'm creating a loop and I assume that this loop is being handled in this way, so I would like to know it this is something defined by the Python language or by the Python interpreter implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dict still contains a reference to the original list. `lista = [1, dict]` does not modify that list; it only makes the name `lista` refer to a *new* list.

You may want to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html for a deeper exploration of how Python variables work.